# BASH script wildcard not working

Tags: bash, wildcard

I'm trying to use `mkdir` command in a bash script using a "*" wildcard.
Full code is:
 `mkdir -p $EXTRACTDIR/$CV_NAME*/release`

It supposed to create a folder "release" in an **existing** "OpenCV-2.2.0" folder.
Two computers does exactly that and the third creates a folder OpenCV*/release, and I can't figure out why.

Thnx for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the third computer "OpenCV-2.2.0/release" doesn't exist, so wildcard matching will fail and will result in a string where `*` is untouched.

`cd $EXTRACTDIR/$CV_NAME*; mkdir release`

or

```
mkdir `echo $EXTRACTDIR/$CV_NAME*`/release
```

if you have multiple $CV_NAME* directories, you have to use a loop.

Answer (score 3):

The *find* command is a very useful  command indeed, especially when using the -exec option. I whole heartedly recommend reading up on it further.

```
find ./$EXTRACTDIR -type d -name $CV_NAME\* -exec mkdir {}/release \;
```

{} translates the result of the search into the mkdir comand.  the parents option for mkdir ( -p ) is not needed because the folder must exist in order to be found.